# Download file from folder in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a website where I am uploading document and stored in folder. Uploading document works fine but download code not works. I need to download file from folder.

```
protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
         lblresume.Text = "~/Student_Resume/" + fuResume.FileName.ToString();         
         if (lblresume.Text != string.Empty)        
         {
             string filePath = lblresume.Text;             
             Response.ContentType = "doc/docx";             
             Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filePath + "\"");              
             Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(filePath));             
             Response.End();         
         }    
}
```

Comment: Try fully-qualifying the path of your file.

Comment: "~/Student_Resume/" + fuResume.FileName.ToString is it fully-qualifying path

Comment: Path should be physical.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this

```
protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
     lblresume.Text = "~/Student_Resume/" + fuResume.FileName.ToString();         
     if (lblresume.Text != string.Empty)        
     {
         WebClient req = new WebClient();
         HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
         string filePath = lblresume.Text;               
         response.Clear();
         response.ClearContent();
         response.ClearHeaders();
         response.Buffer = true;
         response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Filename.extension");
         byte[] data = req.DownloadData(Server.MapPath(filePath));
         response.BinaryWrite(data);
         response.End();                   
     }    
}
```

Comment: byte[] data = req.DownloadData(filePath); In this line iam geting Could not find a part of the path error.

Comment: This line takes file name from fileupload tool not from lblresume byte[] data = req.DownloadData(filePath);

Comment: try using Server.MapPath(filePath)

Comment: sir Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\~\Student_Resume\'. This error comes

Comment: which is the location of Student_Resume folder. Is it in root. then you can use string path=Server.MapPath("~/Student_Resume/") + @"\resume.docx"; and in this place use byte[] data = req.DownloadData(path);

Answer (score 1):

`Filepath` in

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filePath + "\"");
```

Should be physical path; and not styart with: `~`.
Content-type should be `"application/ms-word"`

Comment: `Filepath` should be filename+ext without `~`. This is the filename that will appear by default when download file dialogbox is shown

Comment: how to access the filename from the folder to download. Here it takes filename from fileupload not form folder

Comment: yes sir but this line takes file name from fileupload tool not from lblresume Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(filePath));

Comment: Convert to filePath to filename+ext using `Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + Path.GetFileName(Server.MapPath(filePath)) + "\"");`

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
     lblresume.Text = "~/Student_Resume/" + fuResume.FileName.ToString();         
     if (lblresume.Text != string.Empty)        
     {
         string filePath = lblresume.Text;             
         Response.ContentType = "doc/docx";             
         Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + fuResume.FileName.ToString() + "\"");              
         Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(filePath));             
         Response.End();         
     }    
}
```

Try this code. This should work.